# AS/400 End User - run keystrokes automatically

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

I'm a novice with AS/400. I have a bit of coding experience and know that there's always an access to the backend if you're clever enough. But developers in my organisation said that it's hard to communicate with the server and make it run things remotely.

So I'm wondering if you anyone's got any ideas how I can schedule a simple task. I login to the "Personal Communication", which is the client app. Then I go to a certain menu, ie I543, enter a parameter "1". And Press "ENTER" to run a report which have a file output.

I know there is that "Macro" function within Personal Communication. But that relies on send keys which does not work on a locked screen, nor do I want to activate it manually, which really defies the point of automation.

I was hoping I can schedule a simple call command somehow to activate some kind of procedure. Just need to know if possible and where to start looking? Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how to execute menu option 1 without doing manual screen I/O? Or are you instead asking how to call a program remotely?

Comment: Yeah probably both. I want to execute it automatically. And since I don't have physical access to the server, I guess that's called remote - from the end user PC. What I know is, if I have access to the database from my PC - run queries, download files and login to the user interface - then surely I can send commands to the server etc.

Comment: Just wondering, what ERP package are you using, if any?

Comment: Also, you can use JTopen (IBM Toolbox for Java, http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzahh/page1.htm)  to interact with the IBM i series. (previously known as AS/400). You could place your java program on the server or run it as a service from your PC, but this is much more complicated than Charles's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last millennium's AS/400 and today's IBM i both have a basic job scheduler built in.

From a command line WRKJOBSCDE.

You need to find out what happens when you select menu I543 option 1.  Assuming it's a simple `CALL MYRPT` or `SBMJOB CMD(CALL MYRPT)` then adding a scheduled job to run the report is easy.

However, you probably don't have the authority to do so.  Nor should your developers necessarily be able to do so.  Your system administrator is the right person.  In a small shop, that might be the guy doing development.  In a large one, it's another person or team.

But your developers should have at least pointed you toward the admin and the job scheduler.

Comment: Thanks, this gives me a starting point. Awesome, hope this jogs the admin's memory.